# R optim - retrieving values from individual iterations

Tags: r, optimization

I want to retrieve values of optimized parameters in different iterations of the `optim` function. The purpose is to check convergence of the error on the validation dataset.

My question is closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975101/getting-more-details-from-optim-function-from-r) and I tried to implement the code therein that I supposed to solve my problem. However, both values of `i` and `$count` suggest that the optimized function is called much more times than specified in the `maxit` parameter:

```
vals <- list()
f1 <- function(x) {
  i <<- i+1
  vals[[i]] <<- x
  
  x1 <- x[1]
  x2 <- x[2]
  x1^2 + 3*x2^2  
}

# countBFGS 
i <- 0  
optim(c(1,1), f1, method="BFGS",control = list(trace=1, maxit = 10))$count
i
# countCG 
i <- 0 
optim(c(1,1), f1, method="CG",control = list(trace=1, maxit = 10))$count
i
# countSANN
i <- 0 
optim(c(1,1), f1, method="SANN",control = list(trace=1, maxit = 10))$count
i
```

Any suggestions how to capture optimized parameters on-the-fly?

Sorry for possible duplication of the question mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

The difference in counts that is observed is due to the fact that the objective function will also be called to compute the numeric derivative.  If we supply a derivative then that won't happen and the count and `i` will correspond.  In the example below they are both 24:

```
vals <- NULL; i <- 0
gr1 <- function(x) c(2, 6) * x  # gradient
optim(c(1, 1), f1, gr1, method = "BFGS", control = list(trace = 1))$count

## initial  value 4.000000 
## final  value 0.000000 
## converged
## function gradient 
##       24        9 

i
## [1] 24
```

Also if we use an optimization method that does not use derivatives in the first place such as Nelder Mead then the count and i will also correspond. Try this:

```
vals <- NULL; i <- 0
optim(c(1, 1), f1, method = "Nelder", control = list(trace = 1))$count
i
```

**ADDED:**  If using `maxit` then try tracing the `f1` and `gr1` functions.  `gr1` will be evaluated `maxit` times and the last valuation of `f1` prior to each `gr1` evaluation could be used to monitor `f1`.

```
vals <- NULL; i <- 0
gr1 <- function(x) c(2, 6) * x  # gradient
trace(gr1, exit = quote(print(c(returnValue(), x))))
trace(f1, exit = quote(print(c(i, returnValue(), x))))
optim(c(1, 1), f1, gr1, method = "BFGS", control = list(trace = 10, maxit = 5))$count
untrace(f1)
untrace(gr1)
```

giving:

```
Tracing fn(par, ...) on exit 
[1] 1 4 1 1
initial  value 4.000000 
Tracing gr(par, ...) on exit 
[1] 2 6 1 1
Tracing fn(par, ...) on exit 
[1]  2 76 -1 -5
Tracing fn(par, ...) on exit 
[1]  3.00  0.48  0.60 -0.20
Tracing gr(par, ...) on exit 
[1]  1.2 -1.2  0.6 -0.2
Tracing fn(par, ...) on exit 
[1]  4.00000000  0.55976676 -0.73469388  0.08163265
Tracing fn(par, ...) on exit 
[1]  5.0000000  0.1728560  0.3330612 -0.1436735
Tracing gr(par, ...) on exit 
[1]  0.6661224 -0.8620408  0.3330612 -0.1436735
Tracing fn(par, ...) on exit 
[1] 6.000000e+00 1.207714e-05 1.192941e-03 1.884501e-03
Tracing gr(par, ...) on exit 
[1] 0.002385882 0.011307005 0.001192941 0.001884501
Tracing fn(par, ...) on exit 
[1]  7.000000e+00  7.788526e-09 -5.338595e-05 -4.057284e-05
Tracing gr(par, ...) on exit 
[1] -1.067719e-04 -2.434371e-04 -5.338595e-05 -4.057284e-05
final  value 0.000000 
stopped after 5 iterations
function gradient 
       7        5
```

Comment: In your example the `i` and `$count` are the same, but the number of iterations of optim is different (driven by the `maxit` setting, try `maxit = 5`). It applies both for `BFGS` and `CG` methods. In these cases I cannot distinguish which functnion calling correspond to iterations of `i` and therefore I cannot use information from the iteration. From the methods above counts of function callings and `maxit` value seem to somehow correspond for `SANN` and `Nelder`...